# SVN - merge specific revisions from one branch to another

Tags: java, svn

I had two identical branches in SVN: branch1 and branch2.
I have made 10 commits to branch2. Is it possible to merge three of those commits to branch1? For example commit 2, 6, 8. I know the revision number of those commits.

I would prefer to do it in eclipse but i can also use tortoise svn.

Answer (score 1):

In TortoiseSVN, right click to `branch2` working copy, choose `Show log...`

CTRL + Left click to select the revisions you want to copy. Right click on selected revisions, choose `Merge revisions to...` and choose destination in `Select merge target` dialog.

After that, do not forget to `commit` branch1.